LeakCanary - Leaks with SnapshotStateObserver and NavBackStackEntry in a Compose App
I'm using the Compose Navigation component in an app, but have some leaks appearing in LeakCanary when changing the mode on the phone (light to dark or vice-versa).
Find below the leak trace:
┬───
│ GC Root: Input or output parameters in native code
│
├─ dalvik.system.PathClassLoader instance
│    Leaking: NO (SnapshotKt↓ is not leaking and A ClassLoader is never leaking)
│    ↓ ClassLoader.runtimeInternalObjects
├─ java.lang.Object[] array
│    Leaking: NO (SnapshotKt↓ is not leaking)
│    ↓ Object[173]
├─ androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.SnapshotKt class
│    Leaking: NO (a class is never leaking)
│    ↓ static SnapshotKt.applyObservers
│                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
├─ java.util.ArrayList instance
│    Leaking: UNKNOWN
│    Retaining 19,0 MB in 8217 objects
│    ↓ ArrayList[0]
│               ~~~
├─ androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.SnapshotStateObserver$applyObserver$1
│  instance
│    Leaking: UNKNOWN
│    Retaining 19,0 MB in 8190 objects
│    Anonymous subclass of kotlin.jvm.internal.Lambda
│    ↓ SnapshotStateObserver$applyObserver$1.this$0
│                                            ~~~~~~
├─ androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.SnapshotStateObserver instance
│    Leaking: UNKNOWN
│    Retaining 19,0 MB in 8189 objects
│    ↓ SnapshotStateObserver.observedScopeMaps
│                            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
├─ androidx.compose.runtime.collection.MutableVector instance
│    Leaking: UNKNOWN
│    Retaining 19,0 MB in 8185 objects
│    ↓ MutableVector.content
│                    ~~~~~~~
├─ androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.SnapshotStateObserver$ObservedScopeMap[]
│  array
│    Leaking: UNKNOWN
│    Retaining 19,0 MB in 8184 objects
│    ↓ SnapshotStateObserver$ObservedScopeMap[0]
│                                            ~~~
├─ androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.SnapshotStateObserver$ObservedScopeMap
│  instance
│    Leaking: UNKNOWN
│    Retaining 19,0 MB in 8183 objects
│    ↓ SnapshotStateObserver$ObservedScopeMap.scopeToValues
│                                             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
├─ androidx.collection.MutableScatterMap instance
│    Leaking: UNKNOWN
│    Retaining 208 B in 8 objects
│    ↓ ScatterMap.keys
│                 ~~~~
├─ java.lang.Object[] array
│    Leaking: UNKNOWN
│    Retaining 28 B in 1 objects
│    ↓ Object[0]
│            ~~~
├─ androidx.compose.animation.core.SeekableTransitionState instance
│    Leaking: UNKNOWN
│    Retaining 772 B in 28 objects
│    ↓ SeekableTransitionState.composedTargetState
│                              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
├─ androidx.navigation.NavBackStackEntry instance
│    Leaking: UNKNOWN
│    Retaining 19,0 MB in 8068 objects
│    context instance of com.my_package.my_app.ui.container.MainActivity with
│    mDestroyed = true
│    ↓ NavBackStackEntry.context
│                        ~~~~~~~
╰→ com.my_package.my_app.ui.container.MainActivity instance
​     Leaking: YES (ObjectWatcher was watching this because com.my_package.my_app.ui.container.MainActivity received Activity#onDestroy() callback
​     and Activity#mDestroyed is true)
​     Retaining 18,8 MB in 4084 objects
​     key = be3c9a4a-5aed-454e-830a-53bfe384047d
​     watchDurationMillis = 35047
​     retainedDurationMillis = 30045
​     mApplication instance of com.my_package.my_app.SingletonApp
​     mBase instance of android.app.ContextImpl

METADATA

Build.VERSION.SDK_INT: 31
Build.MANUFACTURER: samsung
LeakCanary version: 3.0-alpha-1
App process name: com.my_package.my_app
Class count: 27875
Instance count: 257685
Primitive array count: 170044
Object array count: 32858
Thread count: 39
Heap total bytes: 42026057
Bitmap count: 6
Bitmap total bytes: 37316166
Large bitmap count: 0
Large bitmap total bytes: 0
Db 1: open /data/user/0/com.my_package.my_app/databases/com.google.android.
datatransport.events
Stats: LruCache[maxSize=3000,hits=133209,misses=239547,hitRate=35%]
RandomAccess[bytes=11691281,reads=239547,travel=75185575277,range=38173124,size=
57603755]
Analysis duration: 34257 ms

Please, anyone have an idea on what's going wrong?
Device used:
Samsung Galaxy S10 with Android 12
Settings:
Android Studio --> Jellyfish | 2023.3.1 RC
SDK Build-Tools --> 34.0.0
AGP --> 8.4.0-rc02
Kotlin --> 1.9.23
Compose --> BOM 2024.04.00 | Compiler 1.5.11
Dagger --> 2.51.1
Min SDK --> 26
Compile SDK --> 34
Target SDK --> 34
